# LDAP fixed length string attribute

Tags: ldap, openldap, attributes

I'm building a LDAP schema for OpenLDAP in which one of the attributes is a numeric identifier that has a constant length (e.g. 10). I am using for it the numericString syntax (1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.36).

I have found how to set a maximum length for it, but no way to set minimum length or a fixed one. Basically, how to set it so that an attribute has a fixed length?